# How to validates sharepoint document that requires checked out?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

I am trying to makes sure that the messagebox asking the user to check out only appear if the library setting of a particular document is set to be required. However, the messagebox do not even appear eventhough the document requires it to be check out first. This is my codes.

```
                    WS.FYPJASMX serviceproxy = new WS.FYPJASMX();
                    serviceproxy.PreAuthenticate = true;
                    serviceproxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                    string url = "";
                    string folderurl = "";
                    Boolean reqCheckout = serviceproxy.ValidateCheckout(urlpath, folderurl);

                    if (reqCheckout == true)
                    {
                        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Check out?", "Checking out...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            //SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;


                            //Boolean reqCheckout= serviceproxy.ValidateCheckout(urlpath, folderurl);
                            string checkoutSucces = serviceproxy.CheckoutFile(urlpath);

                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(webservice + urlpath);
                        }


                        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            this.Close();
                        }
                        //CheckInForm c = new CheckInForm();
                        //c.ShowDialog();

                    }



                    else if (reqCheckout == false) 
                    {

                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(webservice + urlpath);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And this is my webservice method. Please check for me.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Typical Web Method")]
    public Boolean ValidateCheckout(string url, string folderurl)
    {

        try
        {
            //url = "http://it3127:30091/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/Testing%20new%20document.docx";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
            SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();
            //SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.Folders["Shared Documents"];
            //SPFileCollection collFiles = oFolder.Files;
            SPList _MyDocLibrary = oWebsite.Lists[folderurl];
            return _MyDocLibrary.ForceCheckout;

            //SPFile file = oWebsite.GetFile(url);
            //file.CheckOut();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```